# VS 2010 Excel Plugin - Getting Started

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

Ok so i want to build an Excel plugin (custom task pane) that'll act on the selected range in the active worksheet.

Can't find any examples or documentation on how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the references Mitch listed, I wrote an **[Excel VSTO add-in tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200918222313/http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/excel-2007-vsto-add-in-tutorial.aspx)** which uses a custom task pane to find differences between sheets and navigate to cells with differences on the active worksheet. Hopefully you'll find it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

[Office Development with Visual Studio: VSTO Developer Centre](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office)

[Office Development with Visual Studio (MSDN Blog)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160131150924/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/)

[Office Development with Visual Studio Tutorial Series](https://web.archive.org/web/20150703134857/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/05/office-development-with-visual-studio-tutorial-series-part-4.aspx)